# On the direct sum of rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be rings. Suppose that
$$A\cong A\oplus B$$
Can I conclude that $B=0$, the trivial ring? If so, how can be proved?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: take $A$ to be the ring of subsets of $\Bbb N$ with $\cap$ as product, $\triangle$ (symmetric difference) as sum, $\Bbb N$ as $1$, and $\varnothing$ as $0$, and take $B$ to be the two-element ring. Equivalently, but perhaps more transparently, take $A=(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^\omega$ with the operations defined componentwise, and $B=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

For that matter, you can take $B=A$: $A\oplus A\cong A$.

Comment: I can't find an iso from $A\oplus A$ to $A$...

Comment: @bateman: Which version of $A$ would you rather have me use to explain the isomorphism, the subset version or the second one?

Comment: the second!!  :-))

Comment: @bateman: Okay. A typical element of $A$ has the form $\langle a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$; match it with the the element $$\Big\langle\langle a_0,a_2,a_4,\ldots\rangle,\langle a_1,a_3,a_5,\ldots\rangle\Big\rangle$$ of $A\oplus A$.

Comment: oh, so $\omega$ in the definiton of $A$ is infinite? $A$ is the sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, am i right?

Comment: @bateman: Yes. Sorry; I should probably have said, since it’s not a notation that one necessarily learns right away.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true. For example, let $A=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ be the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $B=\mathbb{Z}$; then $A\cong A\oplus B$ (for example, we can map $(n_1,n_2,\ldots)\in A$ to the ordered pair $((n_2,n_3,\ldots),n_1)\in A\oplus B$) but $B\neq 0$.

Comment: $A$ is not a ring, though.

Comment: @Zhen: [It is a ring (just not a ring with unity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory#Definition). Whoever downvoted, please remove it.